# Parallel calculation C#

Tags: c#, linq, parallel-processing, neural-network

I'm writing a neural network and want to optimize cycles to increase efficiency.
I would like to calculate in parallel mode, if it possible but, I have a problem.

My first problem, how can I use LINQ? This is what I am trying.

```
var tmp = 
     (
         from j in Enumerable.Range(0, X.Length)
         select W[i, j] += learningRate * Error[i] * X[j]
     ).AsParallel().ToArray();
```

Will this really increase efficiency?

Second , is it better will be to use `Parallel.For` to internalise cycles?

I hope you understand what I want :)

P.S. Is it good way to use `Parallel.For` to external cycle and LINQ to internal?
Because, if I use two `Parallel.For` cycles I get wrong results.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/understanding-speedup-in-plinq

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0, X.Length).AsParallel()`  An for optimisation and efficiency, well it depends . yes , not not always https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq#do-not-assume-that-parallel-is-always-faster. but you can bench mark it .

Comment: It's unlikely that Parallel will help in this case unless Length is huge. The cost of using threads is quite high. Better to go parallel at some higher level where the unit of work is much higher. You may find SIMD operations to be more useful, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/numerics#simd-enabled-vector-types

Comment: if the list is small, it probably want even use extra threads, TPL has your back

Comment: Are you using the `tmp` variable? You are updating the value of W, is that the purpuse of this line of code?

Comment: @DragandDrop nope. I just update W

Comment: if you are worried about micro optimisation you need this https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet race your horses

Comment: For nested parallel for, this is a good doc on it https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222. I would not use a select for an update . If I do not want to have an other copy of W in memory. For you update about nested Parallel, perhaps you have some concurrency issue with some lock, but how could we know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your code, if I wanted to get the potential benefits of running in parallel I'd change it to,

```
Enumerable.Range(0, X.Length)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((i, j) => new { i, j, X = W[i, j] + learningRate * Error[i] * X[j] })
    .ForAll(d => W[d.i, d.j] = d.X);
```

or alternatively,

```
Enumerable.Range(0, X.Length)
    .AsParallel()
    .Select((i, j) => new { i, j })
    .ForAll(d => W[d.i, d.j] += learningRate * Error[d.i] * X[d.j]);
```

or even more simply, redefine `W` with one dimension, your current code is following a straight diagonal anyway, and do

```
Enumerable.Range(0, X.Length)
    .AsParallel()
    .ForAll(i => W[i] += learningRate * Error[i] * X[i]);
```

The significant point is to invoke [`AsParallel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.parallelenumerable.asparallel?view=netframework-4.7.2) before the operation that you want to perform in parallel. There is little point creating an array in parallel, whether or not you really need it.

However, since the operation you are performing isn't that time consuming I doubt you will get much benefit from using PLINQ. As stated by numerous comments, the only way to test is bench-marking, in Release Mode on representative hardware.

I suspect you'd get more benefit by changing `W` into a jagged array (`W[][]`) instead of a multi-dimensional array (`W[,]`) but, once again, that would need bench-marking.

Comment: Op has a comment saying he just want to update W array. no need to order tmp or anything. It will not be use